# How to avoid null or blank value in target Data extension by using SQL Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I have two Data extension in which we need to update some fields from the Data extension "A" to Data extension "B".
But if the any fields of A is null or Blank and that fields value is not blank in Data extension "B" then I don't want to update that fields.

is it possible in marketing Cloud as here we are using the SQL Query to update the Data extension.

Thanks and in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take our [Tour](/tour), read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question to _show the community what have you tried and where you are stuck_

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this by adding a IS NOT NULL condition to your query.

IS NOT NULL Syntax:

```sql
SELECT column_names
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
```

So let’s say you want to make sure that null values form all columns in Data Extension “A” are not evaluated. You will need to list all columns in the WHERE clause at the end of your query:

```
WHERE A.column1 IS NOT NULL 
AND A.column2 IS NOT NULL 
AND A.column3 IS NOT NULL
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Zuz,

Comment: No worries. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped!

Comment: let suppose we have 10 columns and in source DE and for one particular Column we have null value while in target its not null if we use condition "NOT NULL" then whole row will skip and other values will not update.I just want to skip only for those null value which is null in source DE but not in Target DE.